# Удаление данных с таблицы React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пытаюсь удалить данные с таблицы, и никак не пойму что делаю не так. На сервере все нормально удаляется, а на клиенте обновленную табличку увижу только после перезагрузки страницы, как сделать, чтобы на клиенте сразу было видно, что я удалил?

Так выглядит action:

```html
import {DELETE_BOOK, FETCH_BOOK} from "../constants/constants";
import axios from 'axios'

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/book/';

export const deleteBookSuccess = id => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_BOOK,
        payload: id
    }
};

export const deleteBook = id => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`${apiUrl}/delete/${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(deleteBookSuccess(response.data))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            });
    };
};
```

reducer:

```html
import {DELETE_BOOK} from "../constants/constants";

export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case DELETE_BOOK:
            return state.filter(book => book._id !== action.payload.id);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```html
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import TableBooks from '../components/TableBooks'
import {fetchAllBooks, deleteBook} from "../actions/books";
class StoreBooks extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.allBooks();
    };
    
    render() {  
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <TableBooks books={this.props.books}
                            deleteBook={this.props.onDeleteBook}/>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

StoreBooks.propTypes = {
    books: PropTypes.array,
    allBooks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onDeleteBook: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onDeleteBook: id => {
            dispatch(deleteBook(id))
        },
        allBooks: book => {
            dispatch(fetchAllBooks(book))
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        books: state.books
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoreBooks)
```

```html
import React, {Fragment} from 'react'
import TableRow from '../TableRow'

const TableBooks = ({books, deleteBook}) => {

    const elements = books.map(book => {
        return (
            <TableRow book={book}
                      key={book._id}
                      deleteBook={deleteBook}/>
        )
    });


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className={"table-users"}>
                <div className={"header"}>Книги</div>
                <table cellSpacing="0" id="table-to-xls">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Название</th>
                        <th>Автор</th>
                        <th>Издательство</th>
                        <th>Серия</th>
                        <th width="230">Цена</th>
                    </tr>
                    {elements}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
};

export default TableBooks
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const TableRow = ({book, deleteBook}) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>
                {book.titleBook}
            </td>
            <td>
                {book.authorBook}
            </td>
            <td>
                {book.publishing}
            </td>
            <td>
                {book.series}
            </td>
            <td>{book.price}</td>
            <td>
                <button><Link to={"/edit/" + book._id}>Редактировать</Link></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onClick={() => deleteBook(book._id)}>Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
};


export default TableRow;
```

Comment: В редьюсере замените `return state.filter(book => book._id !== action.payload.id);` на `return state.filter(book => book._id !== action.payload);` и заработает.

Comment: заменил, но не помогло